# WinAPI ShowWindow fails even though CreateWindowEx seemingly succeeds

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having trouble using **CreateWindowEx**. If I set the final parameter (LPVOID lpParam) to NULL and use the returned window handle in a call to **ShowWindow**, the window displays everything fine. However, I need to pass in a pointer to the class that I will be modifying based off of some of the operating system messages that I intercept. When I try to do that, by specifying the **lpParam** as **this**, my returned handle is apparently garbage because passing it into **ShowWindow** causes: "An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback."

I have no idea how to debug this, so I am stuck.

The address that is pointed to remains the same between passing it in and pulling it back out.

I did not define a WM_PAINT case.

WM_CREATE handler:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{

            // get screen resolution
            HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
            RECT R;
            GetWindowRect(desktop, &R);
            int width = R.right - R.left;
            int height = R.bottom - R.top;

            HWND loading_image;
            loading_image = CreateWindowEx(0,L"Static",L"Image", SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,0,0,width,height,hwnd,(HMENU)ID_IMAGE3,g_hInst,NULL); 
            SetClassLong(loading_image,GCL_STYLE,CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW);
            HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,L"loadingscreen.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            SendMessage(loading_image,STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)bitmap);

            progressbar = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, (LPTSTR)NULL, WS_CHILD | PBS_SMOOTH | WS_VISIBLE, width/2-400,100,800,20,hwnd,(HMENU)0,g_hInst,NULL);
            SendMessage(progressbar,PBM_SETSTEP,20,NULL);

            CREATESTRUCT* cs = (CREATESTRUCT*)lParam;
            app = (D3DApp*)cs->lpCreateParams;
            return 0;
}
```

The WindowProc call goes bad on a 70 msg (WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING). It doesn't go bad on prior messages: WM_NCCALCSIZE, WM_CREATE, WM_PARENTNOTIFY, WM_SIZE, WM_SIZE, or WM_SHOWWINDOW, although WM_SHOWWINDOW is handled just before WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, so I'm guessing WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING is just a result of WM_SHOWWINDOW getting passed.

Comment: It sounds like your `WM_CREATE` message handler has a problem. You should post it.

Comment: Or the `WM_PAINT` handler has a problem.  Or `WM_ERASEBACKGROUND`.  Or `WM_POSCHANGING`.  Or just about anything that gets sent when your window appears.

Comment: Most likely there's some interaction between `WM_CREATE` and `WM_PAINT` -- you should post the relevant source for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on `CreateWindowEx`.  Write down the pointer you're passing in.

Put a breakpoint on your WindowProc function.  Check that the pointer it extracts from your private window data (that's where you're storing the pointer, right?) is the same one passed in.  You are using `SetProp` and `GetProp` (see topic [Window Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632594.aspx) on MSDN) instead of `SetWindowLongPtr`, right?

On entry to your WindowProc, print out the message number so you can see which message is being processed when it crashes (you can use a tracepoint for this if your debugger supports them, or add a `printf` call to your code and recompile.

Comment: I'm not using `SetProp`, `GetProp`, or `SetWindowLongPtr`. Where should I be using them? I'm just setting my window handle to this return value: `CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"D3DWndClassName", L"name", WS_POPUP, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, width, height, NULL, NULL, mhAppInst, this);`

Comment: "I need to pass in a pointer to the class"... If you pass it to `CreateWindowEx`, you get it in `WM_CREATE` as part of the `CREATESTRUCT` (you've already figured that part out), and then you need to use `SetProp` to make it available to future messages.

Comment: Do you have a handler for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`?  Is it trying to use the `app` pointer (which got set in `WM_CREATE` but then went out of scope)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have your answer already, but I think the culprit is in:

SetClassLong(loading_image,GCL_STYLE,CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW);

Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize that `CreateWindowEx` sends messages before it returns? That means that your `WindowProc` must handle them. You don't show that code, but it's a common mistake to call CreateWindowEx too early.